# Feature Request - When I forget Tags, can you make the box red?

Tags: feature-request, usability

I had occasion to meet the CAPTCHA today with a cool picture of a robot. This is because I didn't read the error message!

I'd put an image into my question.
Quite coincidentally I forgot to fill in the tags.

When prompted that my tags were wrong or empty, I incorrectly thought that I'd done my html tags wrong, not the tags of the question, I then tried again but using markdown for the image instead of html.

When posting the question, it was now... eventually... that it dawned on me that it meant question tags.

Thanks for listening to the sob story, my request to avoid others falling for the same thing as me is: can the Tags box which I haven't filled in be made bold, coloured in red, with jazzy arrows pointing at it, in the case that it's not filled in?

Comment: freehand arrows?  and circles?  asking for freehand graphics is the way to garner public support for any feature request.  you should ask for freehand circles and arrows (and a paragraph on the back of each one).

Comment: oops - just spotted a typo: I meant CAPTCHA not CATCHPA. I don't have enough streetcred to edit yet - please forgive :o)

Comment: You can edit your **own** questions and answers regardless of reputation.

Comment: Cool - I think I'd been editing too much perhaps and was restricted at the time, I have an edit button now will fix